# Sony Spresense　にて　SDカード挿入時に　GNSS.iso　が正常に作動しない

Tags: spresense

Sony Spresense において　Arduino　IDE　でのスケッチ例である　GNSS.iso を実行したとき、拡張ボードに　SDカード　がある状態では、衛星を捕捉することができません。

SDカード　が挿入されていない場合には、位置情報が取得可能な状態です。
SDカード の形式は　FAT32　であり、　Spresense から読み書きができることを確認しております。
また、　GNSS_tracker.iso でも、衛星を捕捉することができません。

原因や解決策がありましたら、ご教示ください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

拡張ボードのSDカードスロットはメインボードのGNSS受信アンテナに近い位置にあるので、
SDカードで発生するノイズが測位性能に影響を与えている可能性があります。
影響量に個体差があるかもしれないので、別のSDカードをお持ちでしたら
交換して試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
gnss_tracker.ino のほうは、そもそもSDカードを使用するプログラムなので
使えないとなると困りますね。

追記(2019/7/12)
今回リリースされたv1.3.1でSDカード挿入時の受信感度を改善したとのことで、ありがとうございます。> サポート担当様
しかし、どのような方法で改善したのか、具体的なコメントが無いので少々不満が残ります。
差支えなければ、変更点についてもう少し詳しくご解説いただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: fractional_n様
コメントありがとうございます．アカウントが異なりますが，質問投稿者です．
そのような影響もあるのですね．勉強になります．
SDカードについても，いくつか試したものの，上手くいきませんでした．
また，gnss_tracker.ino は特にデータを編集することなく，スケッチ例をそのままインポートしても問題はないのでしょうか？

Comment: @user34798 さん、[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できますので、お試しくださいませ。

Answer (score 1):

自分も拡張ボードをつけるとなかなか測位できないと感じています。
なので、今回リリースされたFlashに書き込んでみたところ、すぐに測位できました。

作られたファイルは、FlashとSDHCIを両方openしてデータをコピーするスケッチを書いて取り出しました。

Comment: Chun様　コメントありがとうございます。同じような挙動が見られる方がいらして、とても心強いです。やはり拡張ボードの影響なのですかね。データの取得方法についても参考にさせていただきます。

Comment: 公式から回答がありましたね。解決に期待します。

Comment: 皆様や公式からの回答もあり、安心しました。ありがとうございました。私も解決を期待して待ちます。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

既にコメント頂いている通り、SDカードの動作がGNSSアンテナ感度に影響を及ぼしている可能性が考えられます。

次のソフトウェアバージョンアップにて改善を予定しています。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: サポート担当様　コメントありがとうございます。改善を期待しています。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご説明が不足しており恐れ入ります。
v1.3.1 で導入いたしましたSDカード挿入時のGNSSアンテナ感度の改善内容についてご説明させていただきます。
https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/releases/tag/v1.3.1

今までのプログラムは、SDカードが挿入されるとSDカードを駆動するためのクロックを供給しており、それがGNSSチップアンテナの感度に影響を及ぼしておりました。

v1.3.1で、SDカードへの読み込みならびに書込み時のみクロックを供給するように変更し、測位時のアンテナ感度に影響が及ばないようにいたしました。ぜひ、お試しください。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム